# Crystal Report Formatting fields

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting

I need to shade alternate rows in my crystal report.

Using this link 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23889/Rows-Coloring-in-Crystal-Reports 
I achieved the purpose. But now i am facing a problem the shading flows outside the corners of drawing object which looks bad. How can i limit the shading within the object.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions:

- resize your objects to cover the `details` section in its entirety
- move the logic from the `details` section to the conditional-formula for each object's background property

I would recommend the first option.

Comment: The shading goes beyond the entirety of the crystal report. Resizing the object does not help as it allows resizing only in report's entirety. Trying the second one.

Comment: Any help on applying a conditional formula on drawing object ?

Comment: Resizing worked using Shift+ left/ right arrow key. It was limiting the resize using mouse :D Thanks!!